# Xcode - CorePlot code linker command error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, core-plot

I am getting the "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" error after adding the latest CorePlot library built with standard architectures.
Here is a screenshot from Xcode:
[image: Xcode error]

I built it from the open source project on git hub, both master and 2.0 release and I encounter the same problem. Tried also a debug both release build configurations. I use Xcode 6.4.
Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you added the accelerate framework yet?  Looks like you may have forgotten that one.

Comment: Adding the Accelerate framework fixed the error. Thank you very much Douglas!

Comment: Hey not a problem.  The_vDSP was a dead giveaway!  Have fun with core plot. It ROCKS!!

Comment: Didn't read the documentation, it must be written there somewhere. Thanks again!!

Comment: Yeah, it's the last line!  As of 2.0 you need it. I can write this up as an answer so it will help others if you want.

Comment: Missing it cost me time..Sure, you earn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also import the accelerate framework. Since version 2.0 you need this. The giveaway was the _vDSP. It is used in the accelerate framework. Best of luck!!

Answer (score 1):

Try Build Settings > Search for Valid Architecture > Double click right area > Click plus button and add i386